# How to mock celery send_task function in django Unit test

Tags: django, celery, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I want to write a unit test in Django for a function which has a celery send_task function.

How do I write its UT in Django and mock celery?

```
def push_to_queue(self, data):
        """ function to add task in the backend queue
        Args:
            Accept data dictionary
        returns: Nothing
        """
        try:
            LOG.info(
                "Pushing %s to queue %s " % (data, settings.SCHEDULER_STATUS_QUEUE_NAME)
            )
            # sqs handler
            handle = Celery("scheduler_service", broker="sqs://")
            handle.send_task(
                settings.BACKEND_TASK,
                queue=settings.SCHEDULER_STATUS_QUEUE_NAME,
                kwargs=data,
            )
            LOG.info(
                "Pushed message successfully to %s queue."
                % settings.SCHEDULER_STATUS_QUEUE_NAME
            )
        except Exception as err:
            LOG.error("Exception while pusing meesage to queue %s " % str(err))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212131/using-mock-to-patch-a-celery-task-in-django-unit-tests?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Yep. Instead of delay() you patch send_task() in the similar way...